# Counting combinations of columns in R (Add count of zero if no value for combination found elsewhere)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with 10 individuals who each have 50 "Element" values. First, I am trying to count the number of unique values each individual has. Then, I am trying to add values that were present in any of the individuals but not in a given individual as a count of zero for that given individual. Below is a MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
nInd = 10
nVal = 50

data <- data.frame(Individual = paste0("Individual",rep(1:nInd, each=nVal)), Element = sample(letters, nInd*nVal, replace = TRUE))

data2 <- data %>% group_by(Individual, Element) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% arrange(Element)
data3 <- data2 %>% unique()
```

At this point, data3 indeed shows the number of "Element" values observed for each individual. However, some individuals do not have "Element" values that were observed for other individuals, and I would like to indicate this with a count of zero. For instance, for the first "Element" value ("a"), only Individuals 1, 3, 6, 9, 10 have a count recorded for "a". Hence, there should be five more lines in the data as follows:

```
Individual2   a   0
Individual4   a   0
Individual5   a   0
Individual7   a   0
Individual8   a   0
```

What is an efficient way to do this? One approach I tried started as follows:

```
un <- unique(data3$Element)

dataAdd <- data.frame(Individual = paste0("Individual",rep(1:nInd, each=length(un))), Element = unique(data3$Element), count = rep(0, nInd*length(un)))

dataFull = rbind(as.data.frame(data3), as.data.frame(dataAdd))
```

I simply appended n=260 rows to the data frame that all contained counts of zero for every combination of person (n=10) and value (n=26) observed. Then, I would need to remove from these appended rows cases where a count had already been recorded for that person and value combination. For instance, the new row

```
Individual1   a   0
```

would need to be removed because I already had a row

```
Individual1   a   2
```

However, I became stuck figuring out how to accomplish that. As a result, I am happy to hear any advice either on how to finish my own solution or how to conduct a better solution to this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish your desired output using just `table` and then returning the result as a `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(table(data))

  #        Individual Element Freq
  #  1    Individual1       a    2
  #  2    Individual10      a    3
  #  3    Individual2       a    0
  #  4    Individual3       a    2
  #  5    Individual4       a    0
  #  ...
```